# Chaining method calls java performance

Tags: java, performance, methods

Okay so I want to know the performance cost of chaining method calls repeatedly. For example if you are creating a game and you need to keep checking for collision detection, you would be calling methods the way I am thinking off. Basically is it worth it to have methods like getters that you are going to repeatedly be calling? For example in a large program having getters for private variables of every class and having to call them plus other methods... Would this reduce performance significantly? Thanks!

Comment: Are you having performance issues? If not, you really shouldn't worry about this type of thing yet.

Comment: You shouldn't worry, unless you've got a multithreaded app and shared states.

Comment: Well a game is most likely always going to be multithreaded.. but why would that be a problem?

Comment: If the getter/setter is called a lot it will be inlined (on most recent jvms) so no performance impact.

Answer (score 1):

No, this will not cause significant overhead. For some things, it's supposedly **faster** to use a getter and setter if they only access a field.

Always use getters and setters :)

Comment: I am not saying that you are wrong but how does using getter and settings result in greater performance? I agree with the usage of getters and setters in nearly all context for the sake of code readability but never had I heard that its actually **faster** despite the overhead of a function call. Would you kindly elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: @CPUTerminator (sorry for late reply) I can't seem to find the article now, but it had something to do with memoization type optimizations that happen when you call a getter without changing any referenced variables and using finals methods properly. Not to say it happens often, but to say it exists